# angularjs ng-init json variable in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat loop that goes over a json array. The array is fetched via $http. Within that loop I want to add some variables to the json object that comes in handy when comparing old/changes values.

```
<li class="machine" ng-repeat="machine in machines>
 ....
  <input id="machine-host" ng-model="machine.host"
  ng-init="machine.editHostDisabled=true;machine.originalHost=machine.host"/>
......
</li>
```

I read on the angularjs documentation that you are not allowed or "should not" use ng-init. But, here it seems strange to not use this this directive. The above code is clean and easy.
Yes I can set it in the controller, but then I need to loop through the json array of the machines and set the values in the loop. Seems too much of a hassle.

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit:
>   aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below.
>   initializing data during development, or for examples, as seen throughout these docs.
>   injecting data via server side scripting.
>   Besides these few cases, you should use Components or Controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference - Overview](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#overview)

Of course I understand that an extensive function can give issues here. But this simple line of code...?

Also, I see the current way of working of many examples all over the web.

What is the rule to follow here ? Adding a controller function to ng-init? But that would be the same thing right? Or is the above code fine?

Comment: That `ng-init` can be done with one `$scope.machines=response.data.map` statement in the controller. There is no need to clutter the HTML with it. It would properly separate Model from View and make the code easier to test, debug, and maintain.

Comment: Add a directive on the repeat set scope properties to include editHostDisabled and machine.originalHost. For starter, this way you're not contaminating your machine object 2) if this needs to be part of the machine object then do it in controller before you repeat as now you have contaminated ui  with logic it doesn't need. I sometimes use ng-init for UI varaibles however it end up moving them in the controller so i can modify them with a strong reference. Sometimes consistent clean logic is more important then convenience.

Comment: It isn't just clutter, imo. The problem is you're putting business logic in your view. If someone else were to come along and try to fix a bug in that controller, they wouldn't see those properties being set. Is it necessarily an error? No. It's just a sub-optimal and thus inadvisable practice.